# How to replace a line in a csv file without sed

Tags: bash, csv, sed, replace, grep

I have a csv file and I want to replace a line (remove it and add new information in its place) but I can't use sed. I don't know, my bash terminal doesn't support it. Let's say the csv file is like this:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

I want to remove the line `d,e,f` and add `g,h,i`, for example.

Comment: I wan't to solve X in a language which is not A isn't a good question to ask. That's because it is impossible to say what _can_ be used

Comment: Assuming `bash` is available, try: `while read -r line; do echo "${line/d,e,f/g,h,i}"; done < input.csv > replaced.csv`

Comment: How are basic tools not supported? Are you in some sort of restricted shell? Can you use `awk`? `perl`? `ls -l /tmp`? Could it just be that you need to fix your `$PATH`?

Comment: Can you use `tr`?

Comment: My bash shell when I use `sed -i` pops illegal option. I never restricted you to anything but because I searched around and I only found solutions with `sed -i`, I was wondering if it could be done differently. @PaulHodges Yes those commands, I can used them fine. @fd0 , I haven't used `tr` but maybe it runs. And a little update, I used grep -v and it works (maybe I thought there was some problem with some argument). Anyway thanks for your replies so far.

Comment: The duplicate has *dominantly* `sed` solutions, but there are a few good answers with alternatives.

Comment: Does your `sed` work without `-i`? What OS and `sed` versions are you using? Either way, if `sed` works, you could `sed 's/a/b' < x > y && mv y x`.

Answer (score 0):

With Awk:

```
awk '/^d,e,f$/ { $0 = "g,h,i" }1' file.csv
```

GNU Awk has an `inplace` option, or just write to a temporary file and then `mv` it on top of the original.

If you have `sed` but it doesn't support the `-i` option, the same approach will work there.

```
perl -pi 's/^d,e,f$/g,h,i/' file.csv
```

will replace in-place just like `sed -i`.

`tr` is not suitable for this task. A Bash `while read -r` loop will work, but is clumsy and very inefficient.